# How to wait a thread to be finished

Tags: android, multithreading, join

```
Thread b = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    location = relocation();
                    //log("location success");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    b.start();
    b.join();

    if (location.y>0)
     {

         location_home.x = 4.5f;
         location_home.y =  4.5f;
         location_home.theta = (float)Math.PI;
     } else
     {
         location_home.x = -4.5f;
         location_home.y = -4.5f;
         location_home.theta = 0;
     }
```

I used b.join() to wait a time until var location receive value from relocation to define value for location_home. But its wrong. thread b and if statement running simultaneously. Help me :( tks all

Comment: use asynch task for that

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be good if you use Asyntask in this case:

```
private class YourThread extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
            location = relocation();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        //log("location success");
        if (location.y > 0) {
            location_home.x = 4.5f;
            location_home.y = 4.5f;
            location_home.theta = (float) Math.PI;
        } else {
            location_home.x = -4.5f;
            location_home.y = -4.5f;
            location_home.theta = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it :

```
new YourThread().execute();
```

Comment: You're missing a parameter type in the AsyncTask declaration.

Comment: Now you've got mismatched types between the declaration, and the `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` methods.